# Keybinding causes only a cursor blink ('\C-t') and no command is executed

Tags: key-bindings, keyboard, gui

This article is about the keyboard key combination 'Control + t' (smallcase 't')

This problem is exclusive to the GUI version and does not come up while using the terminal.

I am using **Wayland**

1. Control+t : The cursor just blinks and nothing happens.

   - C-h k + C-t (Control+h and k followed by Control + t) : Nothing shows up.
   - C-h k + C-S-t (Control+h and k followed by Control+Shift+t) : Works. Shows this

`'C-t (translated from C-S-t) runs the command transpose-chars (found in global-map), which is an interactive compiled Lisp function...'`

Note **Translated from C-S-t**

This basically means that Control-t is getting eaten up somewhere in the process.

Some more info and curious things -

1. Control+t and terminals -

   1. Works in Kitty and termite - Detected by wev ; C-t 'tranpose-chars' in emacs-mode (bindkey -e in zsh) works
   2. Does not work in konsole   - Detected by wev ;  C-t 'tranpose-chars' in emacs-mode (bindkey -e in zsh) **does not** work.
2. wev output -

```
    [14:     wl_keyboard] key: serial: 5101; time: 10021865; key: 66; state: 1 (pressed)
                      sym: Control_L    (65507), utf8: ''

    [14:     wl_keyboard] modifiers: serial: 0; group: 0
                          depressed: 00000004: Control 
                          latched: 00000000
                          locked: 00000000
    
    [14:     wl_keyboard] key: serial: 5103; time: 10022192; key: 28; state: 1 (pressed)
                          sym: t (116), utf8: ''
```

3. Emacsclient -t (emacs client on terminal and tty)
   Works.

`` C-t runs the command transpose-chars (found in global-map), which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `simple.el'. ``

4. Firefox and Chrome is able to detect the keypresses. Tested on https://keyboardchecker.com/

What do I need?

1. I need to understand why this is happening.
2. The solution to the same.

And I need your help.

[Update]
The same problem persists in X11. Again, Control+Shift+t works but not Control+t

Comment: You description indicates that `C-t` doesn't reach Emacs (and the problem affects other apps), so it's not a problem you can fix on Emacs's side.

Comment: I switched to debian from arch. It seems to be fixed. Unfortunately, I was not able to get the source of the problem